# OpenCV image matching - form photo vs form template

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect wether a photo represents a predefined formular template filled with data.

I'm new to image processing and OpenCV but my first attempt is to use FlannBasedMatcher and compare the count of keypoints detected.

Is there a better way to do this?

[filled-form.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGYss.jpg)

[form-template.jpg](https://nemo-responsive-image.live.cf.public.springer.com/v1/resize/width/736/1/url/http:/resource-cms.springer.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/img/6550082/v3/4by3)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
img1 = cv2.imread('filled-form.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('template-form.jpg',0) # trainImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
  if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
    good.append(m)
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
  print "ALL GOOD!" 
else:
  print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
  matchesMask = None
```

Comment: Can you post your input pictures (`filled-form.jpg` and `template-form.jpg`)?

Comment: @ElouarnLaine updated

Comment: `filled-form.jpg`'s link seems to be broken for me. Anyways, yes, I think that using SIFT and a keypoints matcher is the most robust approach to this problem. It should work fine with many different form templates. However, SIFT algorithm being _patented_, are you interested by another approach that doesn't rely on SIFT?

Comment: @ElouarnLaine Thank you! Reuploaded the image. Sure, what would be the other approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that using **SIFT** and a **keypoints matcher** is the most *robust* approach to this problem. It should work fine with many different form templates. However, SIFT algorithm being *patented*, here is another approach that should work well too:

### Step 1: Binarize

- Threshold your photo and the template form using `THRESH_OTSU` tag.
- Invert the two binary result `Mat`s with the `bitwise_not`function.

### Step 2: Find the forms' bounding rect

For the two binary `Mat`s from *Step 1*:

- Find the largest contour.
- Use `approxPolyDP`to approximate the found contour to a quadrilateral (see picture above).

[image: Bounding rect of the sample form]

*In my code, this is done inside `getQuadrilateral()`*.

### Step 3: Homography and Warping

- Find the transformation between the two forms' bounding rect with `findHomography`
- Warp the photo's binary `Mat` using `warpPerspective` (and the homography `Mat` computed previously).

[image: Warped sample form]

### Step 4: Comparison between template and photo

- Dilate the template form's binary `Mat`.
- Subtract the warped binary `Mat` and the dilated template form's binary `Mat`.

[image: Subtraction between the template and warped Mats]

This allows to extract the filled informations. But you can also do it the other way around:

*Template form* **-** *Dilated Warped `Mat`*

In this case, the result of the subtraction should be totally black. I would then use `mean` to get the average pixel's value. Finally, if that value is smaller than (let's say) 2, I would assume the form on the photo is matching the template form.

---

Here is the C++ code, it shouldn't be too hard to translate to Python :)

```
vector<Point> getQuadrilateral(Mat & grayscale)
{
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(grayscale, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<int> indices(contours.size());
    iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&contours](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return contours[lhs].size() > contours[rhs].size();
    });

    vector<vector<Point>> polygon(1);
    approxPolyDP(contours[indices[0]], polygon[0], 5, true);
    if (polygon[0].size() == 4) // we have found a quadrilateral
    {
        return(polygon[0]);
    }
    return(vector<Point>());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat templateImg, sampleImg;
    templateImg = imread("template-form.jpg", 0);
    sampleImg = imread("sample-form.jpg", 0);
    Mat templateThresh, sampleTresh;
    threshold(templateImg, templateThresh, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);
    threshold(sampleImg, sampleTresh, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

    bitwise_not(templateThresh, templateThresh);
    bitwise_not(sampleTresh, sampleTresh);

    vector<Point> corners_template = getQuadrilateral(templateThresh);
    vector<Point> corners_sample = getQuadrilateral(sampleTresh);

    Mat homography = findHomography(corners_sample, corners_template);

    Mat warpSample;
    warpPerspective(sampleTresh, warpSample, homography, Size(templateThresh.cols, templateThresh.rows));

    Mat element_dilate = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(8, 8));
    dilate(templateThresh, templateThresh, element_dilate);

    Mat diff = warpSample - templateThresh;

    imshow("diff", diff);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I Hope it is clear enough! ;)

P.S. This [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403400/5799975) helped me to retrieve the largest contour.

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you so much!! I was trying to give it a spin but I'm getting some compiler errors on line 16 ([&contours]) expression expected  https://pastebin.com/aAtB79Ma
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @maephisto Your compiler has to be C++11 compliant in order to compile my code (the lambda function where the error occur is indeed a C++11's feature). That being said, you can perfectly replace `sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&contours](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return contours[lhs].size() > contours[rhs].size();
    });` by your own sorting function (bubble sort for instance).

Comment: I'm learning opencv and python-opencv , and it is not easy to translate this to python , How I rotate the sample image to match with template image in python please ?

Comment: @Sérgio Hi, In my example the template and sample images are already oriented in the same way. If it's not your case, you can have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041681/opencv-python-rotate-image-by-x-degrees-around-specific-point), [there](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/) or [there](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) to learn how to properly rotate images.

Comment: BTDT https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: I found yestarday ImageAlignment-FeatureBased from pyimagesearch.com https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/ImageAlignment-FeatureBased/align.py